# Recompiling a library from VS 2008 to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I open up the VS 2008 solution of the library in VS 2010 and it automatically converts it. Then I build under Debug DLL, Release DLL. But this only gives me the .dll files and incremental linker files (.ilk). How do I get the corresponding .lib files for the .dll's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be under the intermediate directory.  Check project properties (Configuration Properties -> General) to see where it is